# How to define "if last 2 digits are not ..." in Twig

Tags: twig

I am trying to display the word "comments" in the correct form in Russian depending on the number of comments.

```
{% set numberOfComments = 11 %}
{{ numberOfComments }} {% if numberOfComments|last == 1 and not (numberOfComments ends with 11) %}комментарий{% elseif numberOfComments|last > 1 and numberOfComments|last < 5 %}комментария{% else %}комментариев{% endif %}
```

But it ignores `and not (numberOfComments ends with 11)` and displays "комментарий" instead of "комментариев" even if the number of comments is 11/111/etc. What can I do about it?

Comment: I'd be inclined to wrap this somewhat messy (and potentially reusable) logic into a [Twig filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters). This would allow you to define the functionality in PHP, which I think would be more straightforward.

Comment: I don't need to use it anywhere else though. Just in one place in one template. Just trying to understand how to tell it to go straight to the last `else` statement if the number ends with 11.

Comment: And there are two more things:

1) By solving it, I want to understand Twig better.
2) I have no idea how to do it with a filter and don't feel inclined to spend a lot of time to learn it :D

Comment: Use a regular expression ending with 11$, see https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/228/how-can-i-perform-a-regex-match-in-twig

Comment: @COOLak Fair enough, but I'd consider that a secondary benefit—the primary benefit being that this type of logic is more neatly encapsulated in a filter, keeping your template clear and readable. This is merely a suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was adviced in a comment, I used a regular expression. So I came up with this:

`{{ numberOfComments }} {% if numberOfComments|last == 1 and not (numberOfComments matches '{11$}') %}комментарий{% elseif numberOfComments|last > 1 and numberOfComments|last < 5 and not (numberOfComments matches '{1[2-4]$}') %}комментария{% else %}комментариев{% endif %}`

The regex `{11$}` selects any given string that ends with 11. `{}` are just to define the regex in Twig.

UPD: added missing logic for numbers ending in 12-14 that was missing from the question but in fact is needed.

Comment: Turned out to be simplier than I thought. Edited.